# Go's value method receiver vs pointer method receiver

Tags: go

I've read a Tour of Go and Effective Go, http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values, but still have a difficult time understanding when you would define a method on a struct using a value method receiver instead of a pointer method receiver.  In other words, when would this:

```
type ByteSlice []byte

func (slice ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) []byte {
}
```

be preferable over this?

```
func (p *ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) {
    slice := *p
    *p = slice
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slices are one place where it's not always obvious at first. The Slice header is small, so copying it is cheap, and the underlying array is referenced via a pointer, so you can manipulate the contents of a slice with a value receiver. You can see this in the `sort` package, where the methods for the sortable types are defined without pointers.

The only time you need to use a pointer with a slice, is if you're going to manipulate the slice header, which means changing the length or capacity. For an `Append` method, you would want:

```
func (p *ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) {
    *p = append(*p, data...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an FAQ entry on that matter:

- [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

> *First*, and most important, does the method need to modify the receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer.
>
> ...
>
> *Second* is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer receiver.